# It is possible to catch an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL) in swift 4 osx?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm new to swift and I have a function for image resizeing and it works fine but in some cases it crash with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error. I'm wondering if it is possible to wrap the content of function in a try-catch block to catch any errors that may occure.

```
func ResizeImage(_ image: NSImage, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> NSImage
{
    let newImage = NSImage(size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))

    newImage.lockFocus()

    var newImageRect = CGRect.zero
    newImageRect.size = newImage.size
    image.draw(in: newImageRect)

    newImage.unlockFocus()

    return newImage
}
```

Comment: It crash at "image.draw(in: newImageRect)" and i can't figure the source of the error.

Comment: Signals and exceptions are two very different things.  It's not realistically possible to recover from signals.  Before you go any farther, read through this: https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html

Comment: In which line does the exception occur? If it is in the NSImage constructor: Check for width or height > 0.